In iOS, how to achieve a blur over a UICollectionView which fades from top to bottom as done by Apple in iOS 18 Photos app?
In the iOS 18 beta, the Photos app got a major overhaul. I am trying to figure out how to achieve the gradient blur type of effect at the top of the below screenshot such that the top part is the most blurred while the blur fades away to no blur as we move away from the status bar:

I am aware of UIVisualEffectView for blurring but not sure how to do the above gradient blur type of effect.
EDIT:
I have created the below example which shows an attempt I made using CAGradientLayer and UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterialDark)).
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import SDWebImage

struct Record {
    var width : Double
    var height : Double
    var image : String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    let spacing = 2.0
    let numberOfColumns = 4
    
    var records = (0..<100).map { i in
        let w = 300
        let h = 300
        return Record(width: Double(w), height: Double(h), image: "https://picsum.photos/\(w)/\(h)?q=\(randomString(length: 10))")
    }
    
    var collectionView : UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
        layout.sectionInset = .zero
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        let v = FadingBlur()
        view.addSubview(v)
        v.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).inset(100)
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return records.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: records[indexPath.item].image))
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let record = records[indexPath.item]
        let withoutSpace = (collectionView.frame.width - (Double(numberOfColumns - 1) * spacing))
        let width = withoutSpace / Double(numberOfColumns)
        let calculatedHeight = (record.height / record.width) * width
        return CGSizeMake(width, calculatedHeight)
    }

}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let i = UIImageView()
        i.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        i.sd_imageTransition = .fade
        return i
    }()
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}

class FadingBlur: UIView {
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
        blurView.subviews.first(where: { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UIVisualEffectSubview" })?.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        addSubview(blurView)
        blurView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    lazy var gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        let g = CAGradientLayer()
        g.colors = [
            UIColor.clear.cgColor,
            UIColor.white.cgColor
        ]
        g.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        g.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        layer.mask = g
        return g
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = bounds
    }
}

It produces this result:

As you can see, it doesn't turn out as good as the Apple way. It's hard to say what's different but I think the blur radius or something isn't right about my way. Is there a better way?
